# Use comment permalinks where appropriate in in user RSS feed

Tags: bug, feed

Comments show up in a user's RSS feed, but the associated link is still the parent post, not the comment itself. Example:

```
<entry>
==> <id>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365971/xna-position-change-using-math-sin/9366034?cid=11833115#9366034</id>
    <title type="text">Comment by Jon Skeet on XNA Position Change using Math.Sin</title>
    <author>
        <name>Jon Skeet</name>
        <uri>http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656</uri>
    </author>
==> <link rel="alternate" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365971/xna-position-change-using-math-sin/9366034#9366034" />
    <published>2012-02-20T23:28:21Z</published>   
    <updated>2012-02-20T23:28:21Z</updated>
    <summary type="html">@ksandarusi: That sounds very unlikely - 1 &lt;i&gt;after&lt;/i&gt; multiplication by 100? Have you logged &lt;code&gt;gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds&lt;/code&gt; as well?</summary>
</entry>
```

It would be nice if the comment permalinks could be used instead.

Comment: I think they should replace the correct link from notification bar or timeline comment link. the correct link should contain a `comment11833115_` before last number. i.e. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365971/xna-position-change-using-math-sin/9366034#comment11828002_9366034`. [Here is its links:](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9366034/timeline)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122966/295232