# CW icon instead of the Math.stackexchange icon in RSS readers

Tags: bug, feed

In addition to [this old, but not resolved, problem about RSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122966/587869), here is another problem (but not seriously) that is the wrong (community wiki icon) [Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) icon in an RSS reader. My RSS reader is [feeder.co](https://feeder.co/).

[image]

Comment: Which RSS feed?

Comment: Does it do this for other SE domains? An initial guess it that Feeder is ignoring subdomains and loading Math's favicon from stackexchange.com instead of math.stackexchange.com, as we do not specify a favicon in RSS feeds. That's something you'd have to bring up with them. It works for Math Overflow because they have a custom domain instead of a subdomain.

Comment: @OrangeDog: What do you mean which RSS?

Comment: @animuson: Isn't Mathoverflow a subdomain of SE?

Comment: No, it runs through mathoverflow.net, which is its own domain. If my guess is correct, sites like stackoverflow.com and superuser.com should work fine, whereas all other sites which use {sitename}.stackexchange.com would display the generic Stack Exchange logo. But I'm not gonna go create an account there and set up RSS feeds just to test that.

Comment: @animuson: Yes, you are right. The Tex.SE also has this problem.

Comment: What is the RSS feed URL? Is it "hot questions feed
" (at the bottom of page `https://stackexchange.com/`) - `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions`?

Comment: @animuson so status-?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q: [See this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27863/272127)